# MongoDB: Find Duplicates over TWO fields together (E-Mail and display ID's AND documents

Tags: python, mongodb, duplicates

I have the following test-setup for my schoollab:
my "Database":

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"61a7496f2bbe3123dbecb439"},"E-Mail":"stillastudent@fakemail.dk","Password":"mysupersecurepasswordnobodyknows"}
```

created the same dataset again and again

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"48574850459480954385934859"},"E-Mail":"stillastudent@fakemail.dk","Password":"mysupersecurepasswordnobodyknows"}
```

(Infact my Database has only 10 entrys, just for testing).
I would like to show all duplicate documents, with the following conditions
the E-Mail and the Password (together) must be the same in another document.
So in my case i have two entrys for stillastudent@fakemail.dk with the same passwort.
the _id is not matching.

I was able to find duplicates, but only on the "Password" Field only.
what i have done so far:

```
[{$group: {
 _id: {
  'E-Mail': '$E-Mail',
  'Password': '$Password'
 },
 uniqueIds: {
  $addToSet: '$_id'
 },
 count: {
  $sum: 1
 }
}}, {$match: {
 count: {
  $gt: 1
 }
}}, {$sort: {
 count: -1
}}]
```

at the top i would like to print the resulting both matches to compare them
(will delete them later in the same aggeration)

the goal:
list the documents with content, where E-Mail and Password from one Document is the same on another document.

best regards paul

Comment: Would you mind providing a sample dataset I can use to test with? I'm not exactly sure what you are looking for since each document appears to only have a single email and password combo.

Comment: Yes i can do that, and you are right, the only content of each document ist the id, username, password

Comment: Yes i can do that, and you are right, the only content of each document ist the id, username, password:
```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "48574850459480954385934859"
  },
  "Email": "stillastudent@fakemail.dk",
  "Password": "mysupersecurepasswordnobodyknows"
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "61a7496f2bbe3123dbecb439"
  },
  "Email": "stillastudent@fakemail.dk",
  "Password": "mysupersecurepasswordnobodyknows"
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "61a7bc852bbe3123dbefc1ad"
  },
  "Email": "tkuni70456@aol.com",
  "Password": "letmein"
}]
```